# Show next field of a form onclick and also show an inline message next to each field

Tags: jquery

I have a form with 4 input fields and 1 textarea. Im trying to do the following thing in Jquery without success:
To show the next field whenever i click on a field. So for example you click on the first input and then the next one show up. 
On page load, the first input field should be visible while all the rest hidden so people can click on the first field and from there discover the followings while they are clicking on them.
Now i also would like to show an inline text right next to each field as soon as they are showed and until the next one is shown.
For example, the first field is "name" so when people clicks on it it should read "Please enter your first name here", then when user clicks on that field the next field "Surname" show up and another legend next to it "Please enter your surname here" and so on.
Can somebody help me do this with jquery without using plugins?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
var fields = $('#myform .field').hide();
fields.first().show();
fields.find(':input').bind('focus', function() {
    $(this).closest('.field').next('.field').show();
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/petersendidit/rfPCM/34/

Comment: hi @PetersenDidlt, that works nicely, but would u mind adding the inline text message next to each field? how would you do that?
I noticed taht u "search" for input field, but my last field is a textarea and the submit button should be shown after u click on it.
Thanks though for the contribution

Comment: @sebastian, here's *one* (slightly ugly) way of doing it, as a [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rfPCM/33/).

Comment: @sebatian just updated the example to handle textareas. You can use the jQuery special selector `:input`